# Error code 401 in integration between Shiro and WSO2

Tags: wso2, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to integrate Apache Shiro used in Apache Zeppelin and WSO2 Identity Server using the oidc standard.

So I added the Pac4j libraries in the pom.xml and rebuilded Apache Zeppelin.
Then, I changed the shiro.ini file and started Apache Zeppelin. The new shiro.ini configuration is:

```
[main]
oidcConfig = org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration
oidcConfig.discoveryURI = http://identity-server:9763/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration
oidcConfig.clientId = RrlD...
oidcConfig.secret = wJJB...
oidcConfig.clientAuthenticationMethodAsString = client_secret_basic
oidcClient = org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient
oidcClient.configuration = $oidcConfig
clients = org.pac4j.core.client.Clients
clients.callbackUrl = http://zeppelin:8080/api/callback
clients.clients = $oidcClient
requireRoleAdmin = org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer
config = org.pac4j.core.config.Config
config.clients = $clients
pac4jRealm = io.buji.pac4j.realm.Pac4jRealm

securityManager.realms = $pac4jRealm

pac4jSubjectFactory = io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jSubjectFactory
securityManager.subjectFactory = $pac4jSubjectFactory
oidcSecurityFilter = io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter
oidcSecurityFilter.config = $config
oidcSecurityFilter.clients = oidcClient

callbackFilter = io.buji.pac4j.filter.CallbackFilter
callbackFilter.defaultUrl = http://zeppelin:8080/api/callback
callbackFilter.config = $config
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager


[urls]
/api/version = anon
/api/callback = callbackFilter
#/** = anon
#/** = authc
/** = oidcSecurityFilter
```

When I visit the homepage of Apache Zeppelin nothing happens and if I check the console the following error is shown:

```
GET http://zeppelin:8080/api/security/ticket 500
```

And, if I check the response, the following exceptions are shown:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/security/ticket. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Filtered request failed.
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://identity-server:9763/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration
    at org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration.internalInit(OidcConfiguration.java:136)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:20)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient.clientInit(OidcClient.java:45)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.internalInit(IndirectClient.java:58)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:20)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectAction(IndirectClient.java:93)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.redirect(IndirectClient.java:79)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:217)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:149)
    at io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://identity-server:9763/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:166)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration.internalInit(OidcConfiguration.java:133)
    ... 50 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://identity-server:9763/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration
    at org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration.internalInit(OidcConfiguration.java:136)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:20)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient.clientInit(OidcClient.java:45)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.internalInit(IndirectClient.java:58)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:20)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectAction(IndirectClient.java:93)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.redirect(IndirectClient.java:79)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:217)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:149)
    at io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://identity-server:9763/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:166)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration.internalInit(OidcConfiguration.java:133)
    ... 50 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://identity-server:9763/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:166)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration.internalInit(OidcConfiguration.java:133)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:20)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient.clientInit(OidcClient.java:45)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.internalInit(IndirectClient.java:58)
    at org.pac4j.core.util.InitializableObject.init(InitializableObject.java:20)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectAction(IndirectClient.java:93)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.redirect(IndirectClient.java:79)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:217)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:149)
    at io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre>
<hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.14.v20181114</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

I really can't understand what is the problem. Is the configuration in the shiro.ini file wrong? Or I missed some steps in the integration?

Thank you for the help.